# Area of a cylinder below a paraboloid

Tags: area, surfaces

I have to find the area of the following region

[image]

I was thinking about parametrize the cylinder surface as follows
$$r(\theta,z)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,z)$$
and since the surface is in the first quadrant,
$$0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$$
also
$$0\leq z\leq x^2+2y^2=1+\sin^2\theta$$
Hence, the area is
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1+\sin^2\theta}dS$$

I'd like to know if is this the right way.

Comment: You cannot write an integral of $f \,dS$ with limits of integration. What is $dS$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given angle $\theta$ in the parametrization of your cylinder, the height of the cylinder's lateral surface is given by $$z = \cos^2 \theta + 2 \sin^2 \theta = 1 + \sin^2 \theta,$$ as you correctly wrote.  Then the total lateral surface area is simply
$$S = \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} 1 + \sin^2 \theta \, d\theta,$$ which is a simplification of the integral that you had written.